# What's the best way to find the getters of a class

Tags: java, reflection

I have a `for (Field field : CLASS.getDeclaredFields())`

And i want to find **if every field** in the CLASS **have a getter method** that returns its value

So i use inside that loop:

```
List<Field> FieldGettersNotFound = new ArrayList<>();

for (PropertyDescriptor descriptor : Introspector.getBeanInfo(CLASS).getPropertyDescriptors()){

                //Check for getters

                if (descriptor.getReadMethod() != null){

                    if (!( descriptor.getReadMethod().getParameters().length == 0 &&
                            descriptor.getReadMethod().getReturnType().equals(field.getType()))){

                        if (!FieldGettersNotFound.contains(field)) FieldGettersNotFound.add(field);

                    }

                    else {

                        FieldGettersNotFound.remove(field);
                        break;

                    }

                }

            }
```

---

```
if (FieldGettersNotFound.size()>0) throw an Exception;
```

Its seems fine but when it gets in a situation like this, no exception is thrown

because the program is double checking the getName();

```
public class RandomSituation {

private String Name;
private String LastName;

public String getName(){

    return Name;

}

}
```

One way of solving this problem is:

(its all the same i just added 1 **if** in the **else**)

```
for (PropertyDescriptor descriptor : Introspector.getBeanInfo(CLASS).getPropertyDescriptors()){

                //Check for getters

                if (descriptor.getReadMethod() != null){

                    if (!( descriptor.getReadMethod().getParameters().length == 0 &&
                            descriptor.getReadMethod().getReturnType().equals(field.getType()))){

                        if (!FieldGettersNotFound.contains(field)) FieldGettersNotFound.add(field);

                    }

                    else {

                        if (descriptor.getReadMethod().getName().equals("get"+field.getName()){

                        FieldGettersNotFound.remove(field);
                        break;

                      }

                    }

                }

            }
```

But some psychopaths may call their method **returnName()** or something like this

Is there any better way of checking **if a class have a getter method for all its fields?**

Comment: you already mentioned that a method name is a contract that **can be broken** so you don't want methods that follow the *naming convention* but you want methods with a **certain behaviour**! you have two options here, interpret the implemention of every method or test if every member has a proper modification method...  good luck with either way, hahahahha

Comment: honestly: **rely on the contract**, check for getters & setters and all should be fine.

Comment: @Mertin Frank what you mean by that :d

Comment: a **software contract** is a behaviour of a method and every developer sticks with this contract, means: if you have a `getter` then this method does this one and only thing: it returns the desired value - nothing more nothing less. Every developer sticks with this rule, all over the world. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract

Comment: The _best way to do this_ is to use `Introspector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution was very simple ...

I just created a `List<Method> Getters = new ArrayList<>();` that keeps track of every method i have checked

```
for (PropertyDescriptor descriptor : Introspector.getBeanInfo(CLASS).getPropertyDescriptors()){

                //Check for getters

                if (descriptor.getReadMethod() != null && !Getters.contains(descriptor.getReadMethod())){

                    if (!( descriptor.getReadMethod().getParameters().length == 0 &&
                            descriptor.getReadMethod().getReturnType().equals(field.getType()))){

                        if (!FieldGettersNotFound.contains(field)) FieldGettersNotFound.add(field);

                    }

                    else {

                        FieldGettersNotFound.remove(field);
                        Getters.add(descriptor.getReadMethod());
                        break;

                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: @Mertin Frank **5 hours of debugging can save you 5 minutes of reading documentation**